# Showing 2 matrix reports one after another

Tags: reporting-services

I have report which has 2 matrix reports. One shows details and other one shows total becuase total is not just sum. I had placed second matrix exactly below the first matrix so that there hardly any difference found.
But the second matrix is shown in first page but not in last page.

Appreciate your help.

Regards,
Raghavendra

Answer (score 1):

Can you give some more details, please?  I don't understand if this is a grouping issue or what... Do you mean, as an example, the first matrix takes up 3/4 of the page, then the second one starts, fills the last 1/4 but then does not continue to the next page?  Or are both repeated for the data?  So, each page is based on a personID or something, then for the last personID the second matrix isn't showing?

I'm not sure what the issue is exactly but can you try placing both matrices in a rectangle (remove the borders on the rectangle to preserve look and feel)?  Are you sure there is data in the second matrix on the last page?  Are you using sub-reports at all?

Comment: also - so, its there on the first but not there on the last?  How about the pages in between the first and last?

Comment: Thanks for reply. Sorry to respond late. In report I have added 2 matrix. Second(Total Row) one placed exactly below the first(Detail Rows) one. Since detial rows were more report is shown in pages. Total Row which is second matrix should be shown in last page. But actually it is shown in first page. I want to show it at last page. Hope this is clear now.